# Angularjs push list elements to an array

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**It's a small memory game:** the player has to remember a list of words and then he is presented with another list which contains few words from the original list where he has to decide if any of these words were present in the original list. For that he can click on 'Yes' or 'No' radio button.

```
<div align="center" ng-show="showWords" style="margin-bottom:1cm;">
     <div ng-repeat="word in words">
       <h4>{{word}}</h4>
     </div>
   </div>
<div align="center" ng-show="showTest" style="margin-bottom:1cm;">
     <div ng-repeat="word in wordsPresent | limitTo:limitTo">
       <h4>{{word}}</h4>
       <label>
        <input type="radio"  value="yes">
        Yes
      </label><br/>
      <label>
        <input type="radio"  ng-value="no">
        No
      </label><br/>
    </div>
 </div>
  ...
 <div align="center" ng-if="showOk">
   <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="pushToArray()">OK</button>
 </div>
```

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.words=['Okra', 'Musa', 'Sky', 'India', 'Rose', 'Titanic', 'Onion', 'Germany', 'Beer', 'Run', 'Garden', 'Mountain']
$scope.wordsPresent=['King', 'Garden', 'America', 'Sky', 'Potato', 'Germany', 'Rose', 'Whisky', 'Mumbai', 'Walk']

$scope.playerChoices=[]
```

The first array is the original array against which I have to check, second array is what I am presenting to the user right now, and third array might be the array where I push his choices.
*It looks like following*:

[image]

How can I implement this?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.  The two arrays you show have NO matches so comparing would be a waste of time.  Also, what is color.name?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Not true, "Sky", "Germany", "Rose" and "Garden" all exist in both arrays. This is javascript array intersection - I suspect a search of previous SO questions will turn up several answers for this.

Comment: Do you want to check if all answers are correct? Or do you need to know which questions were answered correctly?

Comment: color.name was my copy paste mistake, I removed it. I want to check in the end: It's a memory game, I present to the player list of words from the first array for some time and then the player has to make choices in this step as outlined in this question, if the words were present in the list- he says yes or no and if all his answers are correct, he wins (he basically checks yes for the words those were present in the original list and no if they weren't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Please see this updated [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kra5Nk54rDwyI4YG9Aqc?p=preview).

To populate the data dynamically onto the DOM, you can use `ng-repeat`. Please see the code on plunker.

```
<span ng-repeat="item in someArray">{{item}}</span>
```

To `interpolate` the  looped item, use `{{ }}`.

**Important** : Just please avoid duplicate data on `$scope.wordsPresent` array coz it will produce error on `ng-repeat`.

---

Instead of pushing the "choices" at the end of the quiz/survey(?) why not push it every time the radio changes it's value? Push to array if yes is selected and remove from array if no is selected.

In that case you can use `ng-change` event to trigger the pushing and removing of data in the array, on the controller. You should take advantage of the 2 way data binding angularjs is offering.

You can then cross check your arrays.

Please see this [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kra5Nk54rDwyI4YG9Aqc?p=preview) I created and I hope it will help you.

Comment: In your suggestion you used different divs for each words, however in my case I have a ng-repeat statement to populate those rows. Can you perhaps show how can that be handled with dummy data in your plunkr?

Comment: Can you show me the data that you are looping? @Nitish

Comment: @Nitish how did it go?

Comment: @Foxx..it's almost there, but check you add elements and on any NO it removes other elements!

Comment: @Nitish because that's the better approach. If you select yes, push to array if no remove from array. You only need to push those data if you select it.

Comment: @Nitish or maybe you want to push it to another array?

Comment: @Nitish look bro, I presented at least 2 or 3 solutions for you. Your original question was **Angularjs push list elements to an array**. I also added `ng-repeat` functionality. Maybe you can debug the other small bugs and accept my answer, I did more than what you need. xD Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes sure!! Thanks a lot :) I just wanted to point out that Say if you click on Yes for King and click No on Garden, it removes King from the array!

Comment: @Nitish no it doesn't I just tested it again. Thanks too :)

Comment: I get what you said, to reproduce what I am saying: run the Plunker > Yes King > Yes Garden (at this stage all other elements are blank, right?) > No America (this ideally should do nothing as America isn't in the array so far, but it removes the last element i.e. Garden)

Answer (score 0):

If you can make do with a library, I would suggest lodash.

```
_.intersection([2, 1], [2, 3]);
// ➜ [2]
```

Or in the context of your problem:

```
_.intersection($scope.words, [$scope.wordsPresent]);
// ➜ ['Sky', 'Germany', 'Rose', 'Garden']
```

https://lodash.com/docs#intersection

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me if you want to check for correct answers, you need to do more than just compare arrays.  Suppose they select "No" when something is actually in the list.  First, I would put a key field on the items in my array so you are not so limited.  Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6DIGzHfG1X4xEUCD5Rtk?p=info)

Your data should probably look something like this:

```
 $scope.words = [{
    id: 11,
    name: 'Okra'
}, {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Musa'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Sky'
}, {
    id: 13,
    name: 'India'
}, {
    id: 14,
    name: 'Rose'
}, {
    id: 15,
    name: 'Titanic'
}, {
    id: 16,
    name: 'Onion'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Germany'
}, {
    id: 17,
    name: 'Beer'
}, {
    id: 18,
    name: 'Run'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Garden'
}, {
    id: 19,
    name: 'Mountain'
}]
$scope.wordsPresent = [{
    id: 1,
    name:'King'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Garden'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'America'
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Sky'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Potato'
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Germany'
}, {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Rose'
}, {
    id: 8,
    name: 'Whisky'
}, {
    id: 9,
    name: 'Mumbai'
}, {
    id: 10,
    name: 'Walk'
}]
```

Then I would add an answer field (you could include it when you set up your data or you can include i after like this:

```
    setAnswers();
function setAnswers() {
    angular.forEach($scope.wordsPresent, function (value, key) {
        $scope.wordsPresent[key].answer = 'no';
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.words, function (value, key) {
        $scope.words[key].answer = 'yes';
    })
}
```

Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom:1cm;">
        <div ng-repeat="word in wordsPresent | limitTo:limitTo">
            <h4>{{word.name}}</h4>

                <input type="radio" ng-model="word.answer" value="yes">
                Yes
            <br />

                <input type="radio" ng-model="word.answer" value="no">
                No
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="showAnswers">
        <span>Correct Answers: {{correct}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Incorrect Answers: {{wrong}}</span>
        You selected:
        <div ng-repeat="a in playerChoices">
            <span>{{a.name}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>{{a.answer}}</span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div align="center">
        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="pushToArray()">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.pushToArray = function () {
    $scope.correct = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.wordsPresent.length; i++) {
            $scope.playerChoices.push($scope.wordsPresent[i]);

    }

    $scope.showAnswers = true;
    $scope.correct = correctAnswers($scope.playerChoices, $scope.words);

}
function correctAnswers(checkerArray, targetArray) {
    correct = 0;
    wrong = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkerArray.length; i++) {
        if (checkerArray[i].answer == 'yes') {

            if (containsObject(checkerArray[i], targetArray) == true) {
                correct = correct + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (checkerArray[i].answer = 'no') {

            if (containsObject(checkerArray[i], targetArray) == false) {
                correct = correct + 1;
            }
        }

    }
    return correct;
}
function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].id === obj.id) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Happy coding!